# graphical cuts on a root histogram using TCutG

Tags: root-framework

I have a root histogram( time Vs. counts) and I need to cut the time into three equal intervals and fold it in above of each for statistical reasons in a new file.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest would be to use the GetBinContent method of TH1.

This will give you the content of a given bin and then you can create three new histograms and fill the bins using SetBinContent method, while putting the values in folded bins.